# Как проверить, содержит ли слово все буквы из определенного набора

Tags: php

Есть строка - "Барселона", хочу проверить, входят ли буквы "слонж" в искомое слово, если нет вывожу - 0, если входят - 1.

Мой вариант работает не совсем правильно. Нужно чтобы проверка **по всем буквам** была, в данный момент если находит хотя бы одну буквы, выводит - 1.

```
if(preg_match_all('#[слонж]#ui', 'барселона')) {
    echo('1');
}else {
    echo('0');
}
```

Comment: ``'#^(?=.*с)(?=.*л)(?=.*о)(?=.*н)(?=.*ж)#ui'``

Comment: Спасибо, есть один хитрый момент - если будет еще одна "о" или любая другая буква, которая есть в исходном слове - то выражение будет равным - 1, хотя второй "о" в слове 'барселона' нет, это можно предусмотреть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю как на счёт регулярок, но мне кажется проще сделать на массивах:

```
$word = 'барселона';
$letters = 'слонж';

$lettersExploded = mb_str_split($letters);    
$wordExploded  = mb_str_split($word);


echo count(array_diff($lettersExploded, $wordExploded)) > 0 ? 'Хьюстон, у нас проблемы!' : 'Все буквы входят в слово';
```

Comment: можно и без `count`

Comment: Спасибо, так легче - плюсанул. Есть момент, если в $letters будет несколько повторяющихся букв, например: 'сллонж' --- то данный способ пройдет проверку, это можно предусмотреть?